# Operator() overlading and inheritance in C++ error

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

here is my problem:

### code:

### file1.hpp:

```
namespace Output {

class Stringify{ // base class.....
protected:
    size_t              prec;
public:
    std::stringstream   out;
public:
    Stringify(const size_t& _p = 5): prec(_p) {out.precision(prec);}
    virtual ~Stringify(void){}
public:
    std::string operator()(const XYZ& _v){
        out.str("");
        out << "{ " << _v.x() << ", " << _v.y() << ", " << _v.z() << " }";
        return out.str();
    }
    std::string operator()(const XYZ& _v, const bool& _status){
        out << "{ " << _v.x() << ", " << _v.y() << ", " << _v.z() << " }";
        return out.str();
    }
};
}
```

---

where XYZ is a vector object.

### file2.hpp:

```
namespace NODE { 

class Stringify: public Output::Stringify {
public:
    Stringify2(const size_t& _p = 5): Output::Stringify(_p) {}
    virtual ~Stringify2(void){}
public:
    std::string operator()(const VERTEX& _obj){ return "What?";}
};
}
```

---

where VERTEX is another object with members values of type XYZ

### main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc,char * argv[]){
   XYZ  v(1,2,3);
   NODE::Stringify printer;

   cout << printer(v) << endl;
   return 0;
```

### }

output is:
What?

when it should:
be {1,2,3}

Compilation is ok but, 
As far as I know, NODE::Stringify is able to print {1,2,3}, because of, his base object
has inherit the method for XYZ argument, but it prints the Method with the arguments
of VERTEX (What?). virtual word is not neccesary, because I do not overwrite a method in
the base class.

As a information: I am compiling in MAC OS 10.8 with llvm-gcc-4.2
using Eigen 3.0 libs (typedef Eigen::vector3d XYZ)
Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `operator ()` in the derived class *hides* the `operator ()` overloads from the base class (which you name `Stringify` in your example, but that's probably a typo, since the constructor and destructor are named `(~)Stringify2`).

You can fix this through a `using` declaration inside the derived class:

```
namespace NODE {
    class Stringify2 : public Output::Stringify {
    //             ^
    public:
        using Output::Stringify::operator ();
    //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //  This should fix the problem

        Stringify2(const size_t& _p = 5): Output::Stringify(_p) {}
        virtual ~Stringify2(void){}
    public:
        std::string operator()(const VERTEX& _obj){ return "What?";}
    };
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that this is only possible if `XYZ` type is compatible with `VERTEX` type, otherwise it would've been compilation error.

Comment: @icepack: Indeed. As the OP mentions, `VERTEX` has a member of type `XYZ`, so I believe that it also has a non-`explicit` constructor accepting an `XYZ` from which it initializes its member, and that's why he's getting no compiler error